# PHP: Remove GIF Animations

Tags: php, thumbnails, gif, animated-gif

Does anybody know how to remove gif animation from a picture using PHP?

eg: User uploads a GIF picture and PHP creates a thumbnail of the picture that is not animated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into GD library for image processing - http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a jpg thumbnail of the image.

For more details: [create thumbnail creation of png,jpg, and gif images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360788/create-thumbnail-creation-of-png-jpg-and-gif-images)